# How to decode the weights in caffemodel and forward an image?

Tags: c++, neural-network, protocol-buffers, deep-learning, caffe

everyone.

I have a prototxt file, caffemodel file, and an image.
I want to extract the weights in the caffemodel file and forward the image
to get a output vector (e.g. 1000-dimension vector for classfication) with respect to the prototxt file.

I know that the file in $(CAFFE_ROOT)/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto define 
the protobuf message structures, and caffemodel file is serialized according 
to these structures.

I've also studied that how to encode the message structure.
For example, if I have a message structure:

```
message Test2 {
    required string b = 2;
}
```

and set the value of b to "testing", then after encoding, 
I'll get "12 07 74 65 73 74 69 6e 67"

But I still have no idea how to forward an image using the weights in caffemodel file with only C and C++ programming.
I want to decode the caffemodel file and forward an image by my C and 
C++ code instead of using the APIs provided by Caffe or Protobuf.

Is there any idea that I can do in next step?
For example, to study other materials or other else.
Many thanks.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code of Caffe is really clear and easy to read. Start studying the `$CAFFE_DIR/tools/caffe.cpp` file, concretely the `int test()` function.

Important Lines:

```
Net<float> caffe_net(FLAGS_model, caffe::TEST);
caffe_net.CopyTrainedLayersFrom(FLAGS_weights);
const vector<Blob<float>*>& result = caffe_net.Forward(&iter_loss);
```

The `$CAFFE_DIR/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp` also has useful code.

```
vector<float> Classifier::Predict(const cv::Mat& img) {
    Blob<float>* input_layer = net_->input_blobs()[0];
    input_layer->Reshape(1, num_channels_,
            input_geometry_.height, input_geometry_.width);
    /* Forward dimension change to all layers. */
    net_->Reshape();

    vector<cv::Mat> input_channels;
    WrapInputLayer(&input_channels);

    Preprocess(img, &input_channels);

    net_->Forward();

    /* Copy the output layer to a vector */
    Blob<float>* output_layer = net_->output_blobs()[0];
    const float* begin = output_layer->cpu_data();
    const float* end = begin + output_layer->channels();
    return vector<float>(begin, end);
}
```